# How to change underlying data of QAbstractTableModel completely?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

This is my first post here, but i received a lot of help from all of you guys, since i started programming.

I am new to Qt and try to make my first project at the moment. My question is about the communication between the model, the underlying data and the view.

I first made the background things (data storing etc.) separate from the GUI.
Now I have a template class `Matrix` and I wrote a template class `MatrixModel` which inherits from `QAbstractTableModel`. This is working fine, means that I can edit the table and the values refresh in the view and in the data from model.

Now my question: How do I change the data in the model without writing a new method?

mainwindow.cpp:

```
matrix<int> m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
MatrixModel<int>* model = new MatrixModel<int>(m);
QTableView* tableView = new QTableView;
tableView->setModel(model);
```

Is there any way to call `m.transpose()` to the model's underlying data? What happens if I change `m`? Does it affect the model's data? I tried a lot of things but nothing worked. One "problem" is that I can't use standard signal/slot syntax because I'm working with template classes.

My last try was to make an update class in the model:

```
template<typename T>
void MatrixModel<T>::updateAll() {
    QModelIndex topLeft = index(0,0);
    QModelIndex bottomRight = index(rowCount()-1, columnCount()-1);
    emit dataChanged(topLeft, bottomRight);
}
```

and I tried to connect it with a button and a lambda function:

```
connect(transposeButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [=,&m,&model]() {
m.transpose(); model->updateAll();
});
```

but that seemed to crash my program if i press the button. I am really desperated xD hope you can help me. If you need more information please just ask^^

Best Regards

Dennis

EDIT 1: Okay so far i figured out (with your help :)), that I have to write the functions of the matrix again in the model (e.g. transpose()) and emit data changes from there (with emit dataChanged or beginResetModel()...) but I can't modify the models underlying data. If I write

This in the mainwindow:

```
connect(transposeButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&model]() {
    model->transpose();
});
```

This in the Model:

```
template<typename T>
void MatrixModel<T>::transpose() {
    m(0,0) = 5;
}
```

my program just crashes if i press the button transpose. If i comment the line

```
m(0,0) = 5;
```

out, everything works.

EDIT 2:
Maybe there is a problem with the data storage, so here is my copy constructor and the private variables of my matrix class:

```
private:
std::vector <T> data;
size_t rows, columns;

//Copy constructor
template<typename T>
matrix<T>::matrix(const matrix<T>& other)
    : rows(other.rows), columns(other.columns) {
    data = other.data;
}
```

Comment: if your model's dimensions are changing, `dataChanged()` signal isn't enough. You should call `beginResetModel()` before changing data, then call `endResetModel()` when you are done. . .

Comment: so if your matrix isn't a square one, calling `transpose()` then just emitting the `dataChanged()` signal might lead to crashes and accessing invalid indexes in your matrix

Comment: Okay I get that, but I can just call that from my model. But I am calling the function m.transpose() from my mainwindow.cpp where I can't call the beginResetModel  (because it's protected). And I don't want to write all functions again in my matrix model.

Comment: And besides that I am trying with a square one to reduce the problems I have to watch. But one thing to your guess. What happens if I emit layoutChanged ? Isn't it to rearrange dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it...

```
connect(transposeButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [model]() {
    beginResetModel();
    m(0,0)=50;
    endResetModel();
});
```

works... model already is an pointer, so i give the same pointer to the lambda function. Now i just have to figure out what is not right with my transpose function because this is still not working, but the crashes are gone :P thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have your `matrix` variable as a private member in your model, so that all edits to the `matrix` should be done through functions in your model. that means your model will have a public `transpose` function that calls `transpose` on your `matrix` data then emit `dataChanged()` signal. And you shouldn't have any direct access to your `matrix` because changing it without the model's knowledge will not give what you want. that way, it isn't your responsibility to call `updateAll` after each change to the `matrix` variable since your model did the change and updated itself accordingly. . .

Comment: Okay, just thought so:P so I have to rewrite the functions for my model. But I read that we shouldn't use resetmodel because it paints all again. Wouldn't it be better to emit from top left to bottom right? Besides that my program crashed if I try to call model functions (even simple ones like the new transpose function where I beginResetModel transpose endResetModel . Thx for your help :)

Comment: I figured out, that removing the beginResetModel() and endResetModel() works. So editing m inside the model is working.

Comment: if your model's dimensions aren't changed it is enough to emit `dataChanged()` , but if your dimensions are changing you should call functions like `beginRemoveRow` or `beginResetModel`, or ..  and then `endRemoveRow` or `endRemoveRow`... after changing the data structure

Comment: Sorry.... it isn't i commented it out xD maybe there is something wrong with the connect statement?

Comment: It just crashes. Seems to be the case if I call a model function from the connect lambda function

Comment: does the crash occur in the lambda function?

Comment: If I debug it stops at the line with the connect statement. But more specific I don't know :S

Comment: The problem is 100% in the lambda function (and the calling statements there.) 
If it is empty it works, even with
model->transpose();
IFF the transpose function is empty.
But if i write something in there like m(0,0)= 10; to change the underlying data, the program crashes if i press the button.

Comment: is your `matrix m` variable a local variable in the model's constructor? it should be a member in the model. if it is a local variable then the crash is because the matrix is maybe using invalid memory when the lambda function is called. post more code so that I can help you.

Comment: I have a private member variable m in the model which gets data by the constructor (which takes a matrix too). Anything else is working (changes in the view, then setData called, then data called to get table entries) and all edits in the view are shown directly.

Comment: and how does your matrix's copy constructor work? do use just a shallow copy??

Comment: hmmm okay... maybe there is the problem... but without gui i think it's working.
My matrix class just uses std::vector<T>. And my copy constructor just uses copy constructor or vector, which is deep copy or?

Comment: See my edit. Just tell me what you need ^^ And thanks for your help :)